# Aura - component.find() called from Promise Returns undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, workspaceapi

I have an Aura component that I'm using as a wrapper for an LWC so that we can utilize the Workspace API (we haven't enabled Lightning Web Security in the org yet). Before opening the workspace tab, I need to prompt the user for confirmation that the tab should be opened which I am doing using the `lightning:confirm` module. I'm able to get the `true`/`false` result from the confirmation window as expected, but when I try to open the workspace tab, I get an error that `component.find("workspace")` (`workspace` is the `aura:id` I've given to the Workspace API) is returning `undefined`. Below is the code that I'm using

```js
this.LightningConfirm.open( {
  message : 'Confirmation Message',
} )
  .then( $A.getCallback( function(res) {
    if (res) {
      var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
      // open tab, etc.
    }
  } ) );

  /* vv original logic - changed to ^^ given sfdcfox's answer
  .then( function(res) {
    if (res) {
      // vv original logic - changed to ^^ given sfdcfox's answer
      // var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
      // open tab, etc.
    }
  } ); */
```

If I add a `console.log()` statement showing the result of the `component.find()` call before the confirmation, I see the Workspace API details as expected, inside the `then()`, though, I get undefined. How do I go about using the Workspace API from the confirmation results like this?

EDIT: Here's (my attempt at) an SSCCE as requested

### auraQuickAction.cmp

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasSObjectName,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightning:quickActionWithoutHeader,force:appHostable"
                access="global"
                controller="ApexController"
>
  <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
  <aura:attribute name="isNotDesktop" type="Boolean" />
  <aura:attribute name="parentTabId" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="tabLabel" type="String" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
  <aura:import library="lightning:confirm" property="LightningConfirm" />

  <!-- applicable when user is on mobile -->
  <aura:if isTrue={!v.isNotDesktop}>
    <c:wrappedLwc recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}" />
  </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

### auraQuickActionController.js

```js
({
  init : function(component, event, helper) {
    var device = $A.get("Browser.formFactor");
    if (device != "DESKTOP") {
      component.set("v.isNotDesktop", true);
    } else if (device == "DESKTOP") {
      helper.confirmLoad(component, event, helper);
    }
  }
})
```

### auraQuickActionHelper.js

```js
({
  loadWrappedLwc : function(component, event) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.openTab( {
      recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
      focus: true
    } )
      .then( function(response) {
        workspaceAPI.openSubtab( {
          parentTabId: response,
          pageReference: {
            type: "standard__component",
            attributes: {
              componentName: "c__auraWrapper"
            },
            state: {
              c__crecordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
              c__cobjectApiName: component.get("v.sObjectName")
            }
          },
          focus: true
        } )
          .then( function(responseSubtab) {
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel( {
              tabId: responseSubtab,
              label: component.get("v.tabLabel")
            } );
            workspaceAPI.setTabIcon( {
              tabId: responseSubtab,
              icon: "custom:custom29"
            } );
          } );
      } );
  },
  confirmLoad : function(component, event, helper) {
    this.LightningConfirm.open( {
      message: 'Continue loading?',
    } )
      .then( $A.getCallback( function(res) {
        if (res) {
          helper.loadWrappedLwc(component, event);
        }
      } ) );
  }
})
```

### auraWrapper.cmp

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasSObjectName,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightning:quickActionWithoutHeader,force:appHostable"
                access="global"
>
  <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
  <aura:attribute name="cobjectApiName" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="crecordId" type="String" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

  <c:wrappedLwc recordId="{!v.crecordId}" objectApiName="{!v.cobjectApiName}" onclosecurrenttab="{!c.closeTab}" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on, but I don't think we have enough info to confirm. Could you try and build an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? I'm guessing something else is going on.

Comment: Updated the original question with the additional code snippets